# Need Help on JavaScript to Trim

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I am facing some problems with my server space. The images are using all the space from the server, making it slow. As it is an eCommerce website, it cannot be slow or we lose customers.

If I have the following:

```
SKU's :
ABC123-001 > catName > Phone
ABC753-851 > catName > MAC
AT1233-098 > catName > PC
```

How can I use trim to make it the following:

```
SKU's :
123 > catName > Phone
753 > catName > MAC
1233 > catName > PC
```

Which I would use in the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var sku = $("#ProductBreadcrumb ul li:last").text();
    $(".ProductThumbImage img").attr('src','http://img.example.com/images/'+catName+'/'+sku+'.jpg');
});
</script>
```

So, basically, the output for the picture link would be:

```
http://img.example.com/images/phone/123.jpg
http://img.example.com/images/mac/753.jpg
http://img.example.com/images/pc/1233.jpg
```

So yeah, first problem I have to face is.. How can I trim it?

I am not familiar with JavaScript so any help would be really appreciated :D

Comment: How would changing the name make it faster?

Comment: trim is used for removed extra space from string But in your code i have does not seen extra space

Comment: Harry, i forgot to mention that each individual picture represents each different item, each different page. Because the server get the image from my actual server where all the images are at, it copies again to the online store server. An example from yesterday, before I post this question, I have loaded about 300 images and they came to be 5 GB?! All the images are less than 500 kb.

Basically, what the server does is copy the images to different folders and rename it: Zoom_thumb_pictureName.jpg, Zoomed_pictureName.jpg, thumb_pictureName.jpg, pictureName.jpg.. so yeah.. its a lot of space!

Comment: I get the lots of images, lots of server space part... and you move them to a new server hosting only images. Very good.. but that would only change the base of your url `'http://img.example1.com/images/` to `http://img.example2.com/images/` or something... Then you say the client side (the user) has to load 300 images of 500kb that's +/- 150 MB for 1 page...That'll take about 2 - 3 minutes (depending on your connection) you should optimize that! loading only the images you should see. And no larger than strictly required... If a user clicks a zoom function then you load a larger picture.

Comment: if you have that many images on 1 page maybe you can go for an approach like [google's images search](https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en)... loading more as you scroll down 'cause you can't display them all on one screen anyway...

Comment: Right.. I'm creating screenshots so that I can explain myself as I think in not being clear enough. BTW.. it does not display 300 images for the end users. Displays 1 image according to the product the user is browsing. The rest of the images he does not see. Anyways.. let me see how Can I explain :D

Comment: Here is 1 screenshot stating the images size: http://screencast.com/t/liI52Zgn

I will put all together in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/YH9uT/1/). I'm not sure what the renaming has to do with performance but here you go ;)

**EDIT:**
Sorry forgot to add the other parts back :) http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/YH9uT/2/

```
var a = [
    'ABC123-001 > catName > Phone',
    'ABC753-851 > catName > MAC',
    'AT1233-098 > catName > PC'
],
    b=[];

$.each(a, function(index, item){
    //split the folders
    f= item.split(' > ');
    /* take the first folder remove everything after '-' 
     * remove everything non numeric and return it */
    f[0]=f[0].substr(0, f[0].indexOf('-')).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    //rejoin the folders
    b.push(f.join(' > '));
});

console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: Well, that function would be for each individual Item. I Was not clear at stating that, sorry!

It will help the server as i got the images hosted elsewhere, I would not need to copy the images to the store server. Does it make sense?
I had a couple of tries, but i cannot get this to work. Also, I am working in how to change each link for each category, well, I am trying to instruct the server to get the images from a different folder for each category. It is somehow confusing, I know. Even I did not understand yet what should I do.I am just attempting to see If Something works so I can start.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I have got the solution I was looking for. The code will be as following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         var catname = $("#ProductBreadcrumb ul li:last").previous('a').text();

         $(".ProductThumbImage img").attr('src','http://img.example.com/'+catname+'/default.jpg');
      });
  </script>
```

So, if the category name is "Phone" the resulting src would be http://img.example.com/phone/default.jpg

By The Way, This code is to avoid BigCommerce servers from downloading all the images to the server.